# In QT5, how to open new window on click event on sub-menu item?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmenu, qaction

I am new to QT programming & UI designing.
I want to open a new window when the user clicks on submenu or menu item. 
I can successfully open a new window when the user clicks on a button.

Below the image of my main window. I want to open new window when the user click on 'password' menu item

[image]

When the user clicks on test button, New window opens successfully.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a slot:

```
public slots:
    void slot();
```

Connect the signal `triggered()` with this slot

```
connect({your QAction}, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(slot()));
```

Open the window from the slot.

```
void {your QMainWindow}::slot(){
   //open yout window here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. triggered(bool) signal is serving the purpose.